# DataGridView not Refreshing

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a SQL table that looks similar to this:

1 | a | stuff...

2 | a | stuff...

3 | b | stuff...

4 | a | stuff...

5 | b | stuff...

I only want to show:

3 | b | stuff...

5 | b | stuff...

So I use this code to load the DataGridView:

```vb
Private Sub GetData()

    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
    objConn.Open()

    ' Create an instance of a DataAdapter.
    Dim daInstTbl As _
        New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'b'", objConn)

    ' Create an instance of a DataSet, and retrieve data from the Authors table.
    daInstTbl.FillSchema(dsNewInst, SchemaType.Source)
    daInstTbl.Fill(dsNewInst)

    ' Create a new instance of a DataTable
    MyDataTable = dsNewInst.Tables(0)

    daInstTbl.Update(dsNewInst)
End Sub
Private Sub InitializeDataGridView()
    Try
        ' Set up the DataGridView. 
        With Me.DataGridView1

            ' Set up the data source.
            .DataSource = MyDataTable

        End With

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, _
            "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Everything works great and until I want to delete **3** and renumber **4** and **5** down one to become **3** and **4**. I have loops handling everything and the database is receiving the correct data except my DataGridView only shows the updates when I restart the program.

Here's my delete code:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
    objConn.Open()
    Dim daInstDeleteTbl As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table", objConn)
    Dim dsDeleteInst As New DataSet
    Dim MyDeleteTable As DataTable
    ' Create an instance of a DataSet, and retrieve data from the Authors table.
    daInstDeleteTbl.FillSchema(dsDeleteInst, SchemaType.Source)
    daInstDeleteTbl.Fill(dsDeleteInst)

    ' Create a new instance of a DataTable
    MyDeleteTable = dsDeleteInst.Tables(0)

    'Begin Delete Code

    Dim DeleteID, DeleteIndex As Integer
    Dim MadeChange As Boolean = False
    Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, DeleteID)
    Dim dgvIndexCount As Integer = MyDeleteTable.Rows.Count - 1
    If MyDeleteTable.Rows(dgvIndexCount).Item(0) > DeleteID Then
        Dim counter As Integer = -1
        For Each row As DataRow In MyDeleteTable.Rows
            counter += 1
            If row.Item("Column") = DeleteID Then
                DeleteIndex = counter
            End If
        Next
        MadeChange = True
    End If
    drCurrent = MyDeleteTable.Rows.Find(DeleteID)
    drCurrent.Delete()
    If MadeChange = True Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = DeleteIndex + 1 To dgvIndexCount
            MyDeleteTable.Rows(i).Item(0) = MyDeleteTable.Rows(i).Item(0) - 1
        Next
    End If

    'Send Changes to SQL Server
    Dim objCommandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(daInstDeleteTbl)
    daInstDeleteTbl.Update(dsDeleteInst)

    Dim daInstTbl As _
        New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'b'", objConn)
    Dim objCommandReBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(daInstTbl)
    daInstTbl.Update(dsNewInst)

End Sub
```

I think I am doing a lot of extra work just to do this wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are any of these methods invoked in a `BackgroundWorker` or on a different `Thread`?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - Nope. All single threaded right now. Only thing I am not showing are the Form1, Add, and Update events. Form1 just calls GetData() and InitializeDataGridView() subs.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Is the first column a `PrimaryKey`?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - Yes, and I know just what the first couple of chapters of a Beginner's SQL book teaches.

Comment: What do you mean by `renumber 4 and 5 down one to become 3 and 4`?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - I want to subtract 1 from each primary key numerically higher than the deleted row so that there are no gaps. I was able to perform the task when there were no hidden columns in the table by deleting from MyDataTable. I then saw that there could be a problem if a row isn't in the original SQL Select so I created another SQLDataAdaptor, called it MyDeleteTable, and made modification to that DataSet and DataTable hoping that the modifications would be sent back in the daInstDeleteTbl.Update.

Comment: The DaInstDeleteTble.Update works, but the DataGridView does not show the results until after a restart.

Comment: Okay, then I think my answer is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to change the way I was declaring variables. Before I had:

```
Dim daInstTbl As _
    New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'b'", objConn)
```

The affect was that recalling the subroutine ignored this line because the variable daInstTbl was already declared previously. The solution was:

```
' Delete old instance of a Data____ classes
    da = Nothing
    ds = Nothing
    dt = Nothing

    If GetAll = False Then
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sSelCmd, objConn)
    Else
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sSelAllCmd, objConn)
    End If

    ' Create an instance of a DataSet, and retrieve data from the Authors table.
    ds = New DataSet
    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source)
    da.Fill(ds)
```

This cleared the information and allowed me to assign a new value. My subroutines serve double duty by assigning two query strings and then using an optional boolean to determine which version to use.

```
Dim sSelCmd As String = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Coloumn= 'b'"
Dim sSelAllCmd As String = "SELECT * FROM Table"

Private Sub GetData(Optional ByVal GetAll As Boolean = False)
    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
    objConn.Open()
```

And that leads into the code above! Thanks for the help. Some of your concepts got my thoughts turning in the right direction and motivated me to clean up my code into a much more readable form.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` the adapter updates the values in the database by executing the respective `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` [(from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The `SELECT` command is not executed. So you need to do it like this:

Insert/Update/Delete:

```
daInstTbl.Update(dsNewInst)
```

Select:

```
daInstTbl.Fill(dsNewInst)
```

Commit:

```
dsNewInst.AcceptChanges()
```

**Example**

```
Private connection As SqlConnection
Private adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private data As DataSet
Private builder As SqlCommandBuilder
Private grid As DataGridView

Private Sub InitData()
    Me.SqlSelect(firstLoad:=True, fillLoadOption:=LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, acceptChanges:=True)
    Me.grid.DataSource = Me.data
    Me.grid.DataMember = "Table"
End Sub

Public Sub SaveData()
    Me.SqlInsertUpdateAndDelete()
    Me.SqlSelect(fillLoadOption:=LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, acceptChanges:=True)
End Sub

Public Sub RefreshData(preserveChanges As Boolean)
    Me.SqlSelect(fillLoadOption:=If(preserveChanges, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges))
End Sub

Private Sub SqlSelect(Optional firstLoad As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal fillLoadOption As LoadOption = LoadOption.PreserveChanges, Optional acceptChanges As Boolean = False)

    If (firstLoad) Then
        Me.data = New DataSet()
        Me.connection = New SqlConnection("con_str")
        Me.adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'b'", connection)
        Me.builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(Me.adapter)
    End If

    Me.connection.Open()

    If (firstLoad) Then
        Me.adapter.FillSchema(Me.data, SchemaType.Source, "Table")
    End If

    Me.adapter.FillLoadOption = fillLoadOption
    Me.adapter.Fill(Me.data, "Table")

    If (acceptChanges) Then
        Me.data.Tables("Table").AcceptChanges()
    End If

    Me.connection.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub SqlInsertUpdateAndDelete()

    If (Me.connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open) Then
        Me.connection.Open()
    End If

    Me.adapter.Update(Me.data, "Table")

    Me.connection.Close()

End Sub
```

PS: (Untested code)

Comment: Not working, so I guess I put this in the wrong place? I'm barely treading water. If I read that MSDN article correctly, the .Update shouldn't fix things like changing an 'a' to 'b' just by typing in a new value into the DataGridView.

Comment: The `.Update` updates your database, not your `DataSet`. And since the data is populated as expected after restart the `.Update` is working. Your problem is how you handle the `Refreshing` of data. I'll append an example, just give me a minute.

Comment: @ZL1Corvette I've appended an example. The code is untested dummy code. Just use it as a reference as to how the the process works.